# Split first name and rest of names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a list of full names on column A and what I want to do is to split the first name of each person on column B and the remaining names (no matter how many there are) on column C. Any ideas?

I have a sample sheet if that helps:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJ7wdxYysklusPhWs85v3sUDrj4h68Z3h_16uoaWxj8/edit#gid=0

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Tulio, I've duplicated your first sheet, renamed it ["Erik Help,"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJ7wdxYysklusPhWs85v3sUDrj4h68Z3h_16uoaWxj8/edit#gid=246208392&range=A1) and placed the following formula in `B1`:

```
=ArrayFormula({"First","The Rest";IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"^([a-zA-Z-]+) (.+)$"))})
```

As you can see, the column headers are created first, side by side. Then below that (signified by the semicolon), the [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) pulls two parts from each non-null cell in `A2:A` — all letters from the start of the string up to the first space (which should be the first name), and then everything after that first space.

Answer (score 3):

The [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076185/11225291) is more elegant/practical.

However, if you want to avoid regular expressions but consider a 2 simple formula solution, then use:

B2: `=index(SPLIT(A2," ",true),1)`

C2: `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,concat(B2," "),"")`

and drag them both down.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Marios! I accepted Erik's solution due to order of submission but yours solves my problem just as well!

Comment: @TulioFranzini you did the right thing. Erik's answer was more elegant :)